# When Product is Disabled it stills hows up in search results

Tags: product, product-attribute, ce-1.9.0.1, search, catalogsearch

ISSUE:
[See screenshot]
Despite the status of product being “disabled” in the backend the item is still showing in a search result. No filters are selected in this search. Just hit Go.

When you select Honda as a search filter then hit Go the item doesn't show up which is expected behavior but the first statement the product should not show.

I literally have tried everything from changing the inventory to "0" to changing Global Setting. This is happening to all products in our store.

[image]

Comment: Have you re-indexed everything and cleared your cache?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reindex everything and clear your cache in the magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the lowest level store view and make sure it is disabled there.